# Find largest inscribed rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a little trouble solving this (ok, a lot of trouble).

I hate to come here with it and bother you all, but I could really use some help.

I'm creating a graphical display where I am dynamically calculating the dimensions to draw some text within.

I've determined that my equation is:
    \begin{align}r &= \frac{h}{w} \\
w &= d - d\sin(2 \pi \frac{h}{d})
\end{align}

*If somebody knows how to work MathJax and wants to make this pretty, it would be much appreciated!*

I am trying to solve for `d` in terms of `r`.

I really feel like I am over-complicating this and would like another set of eyes on it.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So, according to the comments below, it appears that this equation cannot be solved algebraically for `d`, which really stinks.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am drawing a donut chart using HTML5 Canvas.

As a parameter to my Angular JS directive, I accept a string to be displayed in the middle of the donut chart.

I would like to display this text as large as possible while still fitting inside of the chart with some padding.

I have a few variables known:

1) I know my charts internal radius.
2) I know my font.
3) I know the text that I want to draw.

I can determine a relationship between the text width and the text height by setting the font size of my canvas to an arbitrary size and measuring the text.

I now know that at font-size X, my font-height is X (equal to font-size) and my font width is W for the given text.

Knowing this ratio relating to my font dimensions, I would like to draw my text as large as possible with the corners of the text just touching the edges of the circle with a known radius.

Let's call the known radius `r`.
Call the font-dimension ratio `s`.
Call the desired font-width `w`.

Any ideas on how to solve for `w` using `s` and `r`? Thanks!

Comment: is it $$r=\frac{h}{w}$$ and $$w=d-\sin\left(\frac{h}{d} 2\pi \right)d$$?

Comment: Is my edition what you meant?

Comment: It's not possible to solve for $d$ using algebra alone.  In general,  problems of the form $x\sin(x)=y$ are not solvable for $x$.  If I may recommend, numerical methods can help you approximate $d$, if that suffices.

Comment: As I see it, you're not going to have any luck getting an explicit equation in terms of d. You'll need to get down to an equation like $d = h/(r(1-\sin(2 \pi h/d)))$ and solve this equation numerically.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes! Thank you!

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for the requested edit. I promise to learn more about MathJax

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That really stinks. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. I'll make an edit to my question to see if anyone can help me solve this logically.

Comment: If you know LaTeX, it looks like a subset of it.

Comment: Have you considered doing a binary chop to find a $w$ that is close enough for your purposes? It shouldn't take many iterations to find a value that can't be distinguished by eye from the ideal solution.

Comment: @RobArthan Yea, this is what I had in my code initially, but I lose sleep over logic like that. I really don't like the idea of doing that, although you are right, it is not too expensive.

Comment: This is worth a read: http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage8/Lesson/rectangle.html

Comment: @WebWanderer Are you interested in iterative methods?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Iterative methods? Hmm... Enlighten me

Comment: @WebWanderer: you are not making it clear what properties you want your solution to have. "That really stinks" and "I lose sleep over logic like that" aren't telling us anything useful.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm sorry, but I don't understand how I could be more explicit than providing an equation and asking for a solution in precise terms. Everyone else appears to get the picture.

Comment: Everyone else appears to get the picture? I don't see any evidence for that. you reject binary chop while accepting an answer proposing two other iterative methods for an approximate solution. What is your rationale for that?

Comment: @RobArthan Maybe I am not interpreting what you are suggesting by a binary chop properly. If you would like to provide an answer using this method, please do. I will be happy to review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may partially solve for $d$ as follows:

$$w=d-d\sin\left(2\pi\frac hd\right)=d\left[1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac hd\right)\right]$$

$$d=\frac w{1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac hd\right)}$$

One may then apply simple fixed-point iteration:

$$d_1=\frac w{1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac h{d_0}\right)}$$

$$d_2=\frac w{1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac h{d_1}\right)}$$

$$\vdots\\d_{n+1}=\frac w{1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac h{d_n}\right)}$$

And as $n\to\infty$, $d_n\to d$.

We may also apply [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

$$d_{n+1}=d_n-\frac{d_n-w-d_n\sin\left(2\pi\frac h{d_n}\right)}{1-\sin\left(2\pi\frac h{d_n}\right)+\frac{2\pi}{d_n}\cos\left(2\pi\frac h{d_n}\right)}$$

which converges much faster than fixed-point.

Comment: WOW! Thank you! This is perfect!

Comment: :D No problem, always welcome to help.  I will mention, Newton's method will probably converge in only a few iterations, though it is harder to produce Newton's method for problems without calculus.